Firebase messaging notification Swift iOS
I am trying to create push notification in swift, its for a dating app and I want a notification sent when a match is made or message sent, currently I am just trying to register for remote notifications, save the device token, with the users email inside a firebase db so I can recall it later, however it doesn't seem to be working, I am not doing it all in app delegate because I need the users email to be saved alongside and the user isn't signed in at the point of app delegate, I have attached my app delegate and the VC which handles it, any help would be hugely appreciated, I've been stuck on this for days, I've followed all the steps on firebase/ apple dev and i'm pretty sure that's set up correctly. Thank you for your time!
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    // Set UNUserNotificationCenter delegate
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    // Request notification permissions
    requestNotificationAuthorization()
    
    return true
}

func requestNotificationAuthorization() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
        guard granted else {
            print("Notification permissions not granted")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Forward the device token to FirebaseMessaging
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

// Handle notification when app is in foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Handle notification display when app is in foreground
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
}

// Handle notification tap when app is in background or terminated
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Handle notification tap
    // Implement your logic here
    completionHandler()
}

}
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseMessaging
class LoggedInViewController: UIViewController, FindFriendsVCDelegate {
let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))

var userEmail = ""
var userName = ""
var age = 0
var gender = ""
var dogsName = ""
var dogsAge = ""
var dogsBreed = ""
var sexualPreferance = ""
var whatInterestedIn = ""
var receivedImage: UIImage?
var recievedImage2 : UIImage?
var recievedImage3 : UIImage?
var password = ""
var imageURLs: [String] = []

var userDataArray = [Any]()

@IBOutlet weak var welcomeTitle: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    registerForPushNotifications()
    
    profilePictureImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    profilePictureImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    
    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    
    activityIndicatorView.color = .black
    view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.layer.zPosition = 2
    
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    blurEffectView.layer.zPosition = 1
    
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    
    blurEffectView.alpha = 0
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1
    }
    
    if !userEmail.isEmpty {
        getUserData()
    }
}

func findFriendsVCDidDismiss() {
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
    }

}


func getUserData() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    
    let encodedEmail = encodeEmail(email: userEmail)
    
    databaseRef.child(encodedEmail).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
        if let userData = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            
            if let name = userData["name"] as? String {
                
                self.userName = name
                self.age = userData["age"] as! Int
                self.gender = userData["gender"] as! String
                self.dogsName = userData["dogsName"] as! String
                self.dogsAge = userData["dogsAge"] as! String
                self.dogsBreed = userData["dogsBreed"] as! String
                self.sexualPreferance = userData["sexualPreferance"] as! String
                self.whatInterestedIn = userData["whatInterestedIn"] as! String
                
                self.loadImages()
                self.welcomeTitle.text = "Welcome \(name) and  \(self.dogsName)"
                
                
                self.userDataArray.append(self.userName)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.age)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.gender)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.dogsName)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.dogsAge)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.dogsBreed)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.sexualPreferance)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.whatInterestedIn)
                self.userDataArray.append(encodedEmail)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.receivedImage as Any)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.recievedImage2 as Any)
                self.userDataArray.append(self.recievedImage3 as Any)
                
            }
        } else {
            print("User data not found for email: \(self.userEmail)")
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0
        }

        
    }) { (error) in
        print("Error fetching user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


func encodeEmail(email: String) -> String {
    let encodedEmail = email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",").replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "|")
    return encodedEmail
}


func loadImages() {
    guard !userEmail.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imageNames = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    
    let encodedEmail = encodeEmail(email: userEmail)

    // Function to download image at the specified index
    func downloadImage(atIndex index: Int) {
        let imageName = imageNames[index]
        let imagePath = "user_images/\(encodedEmail)/\(imageName).jpg"
        let imageRef = storageRef.child(imagePath)

        let tenMB = 10 * 1024 * 1024

        // Download the image in chunks
        imageRef.getData(maxSize: Int64(tenMB)) { [weak self] data, error in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to download image \(imageName): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let imageData = data else {
                print("Failed to get image data for \(imageName)")
                return
            }

            // Create UIImage from the downloaded data
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            // Assign the images to the appropriate variables
            switch index {
            case 0:
                self.receivedImage = image
            case 1:
                self.recievedImage2 = image
            case 2:
                self.recievedImage3 = image
            default:
                break
            }

            if index == 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.profilePictureImageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Download each image in sequence
    for (index, _) in imageNames.enumerated() {
        downloadImage(atIndex: index)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if segue.identifier == "findFriendsSegue"{
        
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? FindFriendsVC{

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1
            }
            destinationVC.userDataArray = userDataArray
            destinationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            guard granted else {
                print("Notification permissions not granted")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
    
    saveDeviceToken(token)
}

func saveDeviceToken(_ token: String) {
    guard let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else {
        print("User is not logged in")
        return
    }
    
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("deviceTokens")
    let userRef = databaseRef.child(userEmail.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_"))
    
    userRef.setValue(token) { error, _ in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to save device token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Device token saved successfully")
        }
    }
}

}
